# Name for functions over metric VS that preserve scalar product inequalities?

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question, monotone-functions

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two metric vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f: V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ with the following property:

$\forall \vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z} \in V_1$ such that $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \lt \vec{x} \cdot \vec{z}$, then $f(\vec{x}) \cdot f(\vec{y}) \lt f(\vec{x}) \cdot f(\vec{z})$

Is there a name for such a function property? Or for a related property (eg. relating angles between input/output vectors and not complete scalar product)?

(Context: dimensionality reduction)

Comment: Is it safe to assume $f$ is not necessarily linear?

Comment: @Aruralreader yes it is

Comment: Are you assuming real vector spaces?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am yes. Edited.